# Save image without extension

Tags: php, image

I'm using a function to save images from URL to disk. Works fine for the traditional formats (jpg/gif/png) but not for webp files. I'm using imagecreatefromwebp() function to save the image as jpg, but it is just black.

Piece of code I'm using now:

```
$source = "https://somethinghere";
$stype = explode(".", $source);
$stype = $stype[count($stype)-1];

switch($stype) {
 case 'gif':
  $imghandle = imagecreatefromgif($source);
  echo "Found .gif <br>";
  break;
case 'jpg':
  $imghandle = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
  echo "Found .jpg <br>";
  break;
 case 'jpeg':
  $imghandle = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
  echo "Found .jpeg <br>";
  break;
 case 'png':
  $imghandle = imagecreatefrompng($source);
  echo "Found .png <br>";
  break;
 default:
  $imghandle = imagecreatefromwebp($source);
  echo "Found default <br>";
  break;
}
```

Comment: How is `$type` determined?

Comment: when I click save as on that image in your link it suggests it's a .webp file (at least in Chrome, anyway, IE 11 just won't download it as you mentioned). You know that a file extension doesn't actually tell you the file type though? It's just a hint, done by convention. I could rename that file .xlsx and it would still be an image. Equally I could give it no extension at all and it would still be an image. Also I'm not even sure of the relevance of this link you posted. What does it have to do with your code, since you claim not be able even to download it?

Comment: Lastly how are `$type` and `$source` in your code populated in the first place? If you have some file with no extension (or an incorrect extension) you'll have to find some other way of determining what type of image it might be, assuming it even _is_ an image, or you'll have to throw an error.

Comment: Ok, maybe I should change the question. I know it's a webp file, but how do I download it using php? I'm using imagecreatefromwebp() to save it as a jpg, but it still is black. The URL is just a file example that I want to download.

Added the $type piece of code, it's a simple explode of the source URL.

Comment: " how do I download it" if you managed to use an imagecreate... function on it, then you must have downloaded it already. PHP can't process the file without fetching it from the remote server first. I would guess that the file is either not really a webp file, or is a bit corrupted in some way that PHP can't cope with, or you fetched the wrong resource. Lots of possibilities. Find another WebP file and try that. Download the file manually (you can use Chrome), save it to disk and process it from there...try and narrow down the problem.